# Need help in converting Oracle trigger to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-trigger

I need help in converting the below query to postgres. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
 CREATE TRIGGER REQUESTOR_TRG
    BEFORE INSERT ON REQUESTOR 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
      BEGIN
        IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
          SELECT REQUESTOR_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
        END IF;
      END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
    END;
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use a desired sequence in Postgres, you may do.

```
create sequence REQUESTOR_SEQ;
create table REQUESTOR ( id int DEFAULT NEXTVAL('requestor_seq') )
```

Otherwise a `serial` column would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you don't use sequences for this purpose.  Just use a `serial` column and dispense with the trigger:

```
create table requestor (
    id serial primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Comment: Thanks ! is this right ?create table requestor (
    id serial primary key,
);

CREATE FUNCTION REQUESTOR_TRG() RETURNS trigger AS $REQUESTOR_TRG$
    BEGIN
  IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
   SELECT REQUESTOR_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$REQUESTOR_TRG$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER REQUESTOR_TRG BEFORE INSERT ON REQUESTOR
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION REQUESTOR_TRG();

Comment: @dineshbalajibingo . . . That is not at all what I am saying.  Fix the table to use a serial column rather than using a trigger.

Comment: @dineshbalajibingo - in PostgreSQL you don't need the trigger or the sequence. Forget about them. Change the definition of your ID column as shown in the answer above and you're done.